# Xcode UITableView in UIViewController doesnt shows content

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

i have a Problem, i have a UITableView in my UIViewController, but when i add content to my UITableView and reload the data nothing happens.

My UIViewController:

```
@interface WPCreateViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIActionSheetDelegate> {
    ....
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewEntities;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *entities;
    ....
    - (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)addEntities:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)deleteEntities:(id)sender;
}
```

And the implementation is like that:

```
@implementation WPCreateViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ....
    [self.tableViewEntities setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
    [self.entities setArray:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]];

    ....
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.entities count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellID = @"WPEntityCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[self.entities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.entities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

If i try to add something nothing happens as i say, i have this method connected with a button

```
- (IBAction)addEntities:(id)sender {
    Entity *temp = [[Entity alloc] init];
    temp.name = @"Test";
    temp.description = @"TestTest";

    [self.entities addObject:temp];

    [self.tableViewEntities reloadData];
}
```

By the way all connections are correctly set, so why the uitableview doesnt shows anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your view controller as the delegate and dataSource for the tableView.

Comment: I did this already in my interface builder, doesnt wor even if i do it in code

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the numberOfSectionsInTableView: or numberOfRowsInSection: methods, does it ever get hit?